# How to reduce Plotly HTML size in Python?

Tags: python, html, optimization, plotly

I am doing three plots:
Line plot, Boxplot and Histogram.
All these plots don't really need hoverinfo. Also these plots **don't really need to plot each point of the data.**

[image: Three plots]

Ass you can see the plots are very simple, however, when dealing with huge data (30 million of observations) the html results weights 5 MBs, which is a lot because there are 100 plots more like this.

At the moment I have made some optimizations...

- When saving to html I put these parameters:

  fig.to_html( include_plotlyjs="cdn", full_html=False)

*Which reduces plot size a lot, however **is not enough**.*

I have also tried in the Line plot specifying this parameter `line = {"simplify":True}` and `hoverinfo = "skip"`. However, file size is almost the same.

Any help/ workaround is appreciated

Comment: With the steps you've already taken, I think this is as good as it gets. Just curious; If you don't need each point of the data, and you don't need hoverinfo, why not go with an image file instead? I'm guessing the answer is that you'd like *some* interactivity?

Comment: The histograms and boxplot shouldn't take up that much space, so maybe use an image for just the line plot.

Comment: thank you @jayveesea and for your commentaries, however using image (png, jpeg, jpg, ...) is very slow to save ( I have to save lots of figures) so image is not an option either.

Comment: @vestland Yes, I would like some interactivity but mainly saving the figures in html is much  faster than in png, jpeg, etc...

Comment: just running some quick tests it seems there's a tradeoff between runtime (html is better) and file size (image is better)... perhaps in this case plotly is not the right tool?  maybe [maplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/index.html) or [matplotlib+mpld3](http://mpld3.github.io/modules/API.html#mpld3.save_html)? especially if you need to strip away the plotly features.

Comment: I will give it a try to matplotlib+mpld3.  The problem is that I wanted to do histograms that shared Y axis, and combine this with boxplots and lineplots, the problem is that for sharing Y axis needed to use seaborn and this type  of seaborn plot was not compatible with matplotlib subplots. Large history...